# Predicting web styling in `design` time when using inheritance

Tags: html, css

**Is there a way to predict, when using css inheritance, how an element will behave (look like) when seeing just the css? Without seeing the HTML?**

If I understand correctly, css inheritance is actually done by HTML inheritance, meaning that I **cannot** state that a specific style `D` must inherit from another style `B`.

Example of a styling prediction problem:

```
.B {
}
.D {
  color: blue;
}
.D .B {
  color: green;
}
```

This means that elements with the `D` style class, might either have the blue or green color - depending on the HTML inheritance.

Is there a way to get all the styles of `B` in advance (like c++/Java class inheritance) with the **option to override some**? This way, an element's L&F can be predicted in compile time.

Comment: Um, in your example, elements with the `D` class will always have color blue, it's elements _inside_ it plus have `B` class that will have color green.

Comment: By compile time, I meant design time - without the need to open a browser or right the html. Changed the question's title from compile to design.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.... The CSS means nothing without seeing the HTML it applies to.

Comment: @sevenseacat - I thought that one of the points in css-html separation is Styling-logic separation. I'm trying to figure out how to have styling make more sense in develop time.

Comment: By L&F do you mean "look and feel", and are you referring specifically to JavaFX Look and Feel defaults, or just the general aesthetic appearance?

Comment: @TylerH - general Look & Feel.